# Are there good lower bounds for the partial sums of the series $\sum 1/\log(n)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, logarithms, real-numbers

> Consider the partial sums $$S_n = \sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{\log(k)}.$$ Are there good **lower** bounds for $S_n$ as $n\to\infty$ ?

I am not necessarily looking for sharp bounds (although they would be nice), just one that is fair.

Of course a "good" lower bound would be one that go "very" fast to infinity.

Comment: You can get some lower bound by first transforming to log with base 2 and then just estimating each term by the next smallest power of $2$. If that is 'good' enough for your purpose I can write it up as an answer.

Comment: @quarague thank you for your comment. For my purposes I am actually avoiding powers in the estimates. I think that maybe the best way is to use the integral test and estimate it by taking the estimates that we know for the exponential integral (which is the same integral after a change of variables). There is a nice bound for the exponential integral in here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $1/\ln x$ is decreasing on $[2,\infty),$ we have

$$\tag 1 I_n=\int_2^n \frac{dt}{\ln t} \le S_n.$$

Integrating by parts shows

$$\tag 2 I_n =\frac{n}{\ln n}-\frac{2}{\ln 2}+ \int_2^n \frac{dt}{(\ln t)^2}.$$

Is $(2)$ a decent lower bound of $S_n?$ I would say yes, given that as $n\to \infty,$

$$\tag 3 S_n\sim \frac{n}{\ln n}$$

and

$$\tag 4\int_2^n \frac{dt}{(\ln t)^2} \sim \frac{n}{(\ln n)^2}.$$

You can verify $(3)$ using Stolz-Cesaro, and $(4)$ by using L'Hopital.

Answer (score 2):

We can use $\sqrt{n} \ge \log(n)$ to get a lower bound as

$$\sum_{k=2}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \approx 2 \sqrt{n} - \text{small constant}$$

Which is a fast enough divergence to $\infty$ I suppose.

Similarly, I believe you should be able to get $n^{1-\epsilon}$ for any $1 > \epsilon > 0$

Answer (score 1):

Note that
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\ln k} &= \frac{1}{\ln n - (\ln n - \ln k)}\\
& = \frac{1}{\ln n}\ \frac{1}{1 - \frac{\ln n - \ln k}{\ln n}}\\
&= \frac{1}{\ln n } \Big[1 + \Big(\frac{\ln n - \ln k}{\ln n}\Big) + \Big(\frac{\ln n - \ln k}{\ln n}\Big)^2 + \Big(\frac{\ln n - \ln k}{\ln n}\Big)^3
+ \cdots \Big].
\end{align}
Let
$$\phi_m(n) = \sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{\ln n } \Big(\frac{\ln n - \ln k}{\ln n}\Big)^m, \quad m = 0, 1, 2, \cdots$$
We have
\begin{align}
\phi_0(n) &= \frac{n-1}{\ln n},\\
\phi_1(n) &= \frac{n-1}{\ln n} - \frac{\ln n!}{\ln^2 n}\ \sim\ \frac{n}{\ln^2 n}\quad \mathrm{as}\quad n\to \infty\quad \mathrm{Stirling's}\ \mathrm{formula}\\
\phi_m(n) &\sim \frac{m! n}{\ln^{m+1} n}\quad \mathrm{as}\quad n\to \infty, \quad \mathrm{for}\quad m=2, 3, \cdots\quad \mathrm{Maple}\ \mathrm{software}.
\end{align}
Thus, we have $\phi_{m+1}(n) = o(\phi_m(n))$ as $n\to \infty$. Remark: We only verified some small $m$ by using Maple software which is not a complete proof.

We have an expansion
$$S_n = \phi_0(n) + \phi_1(n) + \cdots,$$
any partial sum of which is a lower bound of $S_n$, for example,
$$S_n > \phi_0(n) + \phi_1(n) = \frac{2(n-1)}{\ln n} - \frac{\ln n!}{\ln^2 n}$$
for all $n\ge 2$ (the bound is good for $n\to \infty$).

Remark: Can we show that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{S_n}{\phi_0(n) + \phi_1(n)} = 1?$$